# error while installing oracle 11gR2 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 right now and trying to install oracle in it.

I'm following instructions from here http://www2.hawaii.edu/~lipyeow/ics321/2015spr/installoracle11g.html

But when I reach point 9 (oracle install)...getting error like

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 362: awk: command not found
```

Can anyone help me to get out from this ?

I'm using root's one of user for this installation

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

Step 8 in your instructions:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
```

Can you verify this worked? e.g.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/awk
ls -l /bin/awk
```

If the first ls worked but second one gives file not found then review all your steps as it appear some might have been missed or did not work.

If bothese these work, then check the PATH. Are you running the install as the "Oracle" user? Then check the PATH includes /bin. Check as follows (assuming the username is oracle):

```
sudo su - oracle
which awk
echo $PATH
```

Comment: that's worked, Thanks...may I know are you familiar with this error....http://prnt.sc/az0ono

Comment: I cannot see an error in you screenshot. Looks like info messages.

Comment: Better if you post another question.

Comment: chown reported invalid user "oracle:dba" - you haven't created the user specified, which is probably why the database creation failed, hence why you get the Oracle not available. Doesn't sound to me like you are following the instructions to the letter, seemingly having missed a few key steps.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` isn't installed, use `apt-get` to install it, i.e.:

```
apt-get install gawk
```

Comment: can you use `apt-get install awk`, I'm not sure because I don't have ubuntu installed

Comment: Hey, that worked using gawk, but when I run the next step, it shows this error...Lenovo-G580:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log# tail -f cloneDBCreation.log 
alter system disable restricted session
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available 
Process ID: 0 
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0